# nyc merge behaves differently locally than on circle ci

Tags: code-coverage, cypress, circleci, nyc

I am using nyc merge to combine my Cypress and Jest code coverage reports. When I execute the below steps locally, I get the combined report that I would expect (coverage is a bit more than either suite provides individually). I am executing the exact same steps in CircleCI and the combined report contains ONLY the Jest results. I have used SSH to verify that the Cypress coverage report is indeed being generated and copied around properly. I have verified that I am running the same version of nyc locally and on CircleCI (15.1.0).

```
            mkdir -p reports
            cp jest-coverage/coverage-final.json reports/from-jest.json
            cp cypress-coverage/coverage-final.json reports/from-cypress.json
            mkdir -p .nyc_output
            npx nyc merge reports
            cp coverage.json .nyc_output/out.json
            npx nyc report --reporter=lcov --reporter=text --report-dir=reports
```

Comment: I get the same issue; only getting the Jest reports in CircleCI when I merge the reports. Can confirm both the jest and the cypress artifacts are there, but I can only get the combined report locally. Something about the CircleCI container must be conflicting with the merge.